# How to change the type of user input? javascript

Tags: javascript

Here, `userchoice` is a value from a selected list in HTML which is either Matthew, Mark, Luke or John. I created a function called `generate` which takes input as parenthesis.

But when I call it with `userchoice`, the value of `userchoice` comes as a string and the code does not work. What I want is to take input from the user i.e. Matthew, Mark, Luke, John. So I created objects with similar name.

Does it have some solution or some other ways to do it?

```js
let userchoice;
let Matthew = {
  verse: [`Hi matthew`, `Hello God`, `hello guiye`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};

let Mark = {
  verse: [`Hi Mark`, `Hello God`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};
let Luke = {
  verse: [`Hi Luke`, `Hello God`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};
let John = {
  verse: [`Hi John`, `Hello God`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};

document.querySelector('#generate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  userChoice = document.querySelector('#selectValue').value;
  generate(userchoice);

});

function generate(input) {
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Matthew.verse.length);
  verseResult = input.verse[randomNumber];
  bookResult = input.book[randomNumber];
  displayVerse.innerText = verseResult;
  displayBook.innerText = bookResult;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Choose a book :
  <select id="selectValue">
    <option value="Matthew">Matthew</option>
    <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
    <option value="Luke">Luke</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div class="btn">
  <button id="generate">Generate</button>
</div>
<p>Verse:<span id="verse"></span></p>
<p>Book:<span id="book"></span></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's tough to answer this question without seeing how you've defined your HTML `select` you mention?

Comment: Looks like HTML tag with id `#generate` is not found.

Comment: @esqew i have updated the question with HTML.

Comment: @DNT i think that isnot a problem

Comment: I see a bunch of minor to not so minor problems. First, don't use PascalCase to name vars, especially objects, since this pattern is reserved to classes in OOP. You're also using different casing for `userchoice` (which becomes `userChoice` inside the event listener). Also the design can be greatly improved - naming lots of similar vars in the global scope that way makes the code less scalable. You should store your vars as properties of an object.

Comment: @gyohza Thanks for suggestion. I am still not confident with javascript. I am trying to improve and your suggestion means lot to me. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :) You'll get the hang of it in no time. I highly suggest you take a look at [Scrimba's courses](https://scrimba.com/allcourses) (some free JS courses there) to up your game. You can also practice in [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/).

Comment: @mplungjan I am sorry . i am new to stack overflow. I found both answer helpful but I did not know only I can accept one answer.

Comment: @mplungjan I have accepted your answer. :)

Comment: No force! Just curious which one you liked the most and why :)

Comment: @mplungjan  You have explained lot and it was much helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the whole list of evangelists an object.

NOTE: You could run this onchange instead:

```
document.getElementById('selectValue').addEventListener('change', function() {
  generate(this.value);
});
```

Anyway:

```js
let chapters = {
  Matthew : {
    verse: [`Hi matthew`, `Hello God`, `hello guiye`],
    book: [`Mark`, `john`]
  },
  Mark : {
    verse: [`Hi Mark`, `Hello God`],
    book: [`Mark`, `john`]
  },
  Luke : {
   verse: [`Hi Luke`, `Hello God`],
   book: [`Mark`, `john`]
  },
  John : {
    verse: [`Hi John`, `Hello God`],
    book: [`Mark`, `john`]
  }
};  

// generate the dropdown from the chapters object's keys
document.getElementById("selectValue").innerHTML += Object.keys(chapters)
    .map(chapter => `<option value="${chapter}">${chapter}</option>`).join(""); 
    
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const userChoice = document.getElementById('selectValue').value;
  generate(userChoice);
});

const generate = userChoice => {
  if (!userChoice) return;
  chapter = chapters[userChoice]; // get the selected gospel
  const verse = Math.floor(Math.random() * chapter.verse.length); // you have different lengths 
  const book = Math.floor(Math.random() * chapter.book.length);   // so you need two random numbers

  document.getElementById("displayVerse").innerText = chapter.verse[verse];
  document.getElementById("displayBook").innerText = chapter.book[book];
};
```

```html
<select id="selectValue">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="generate" value="Generate" />
<div id="displayVerse"></div>
<div id="displayBook"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make your variables properties on an object, then properties on that object can be selected by a string.  For example:

```js
let userchoice;
let Matthew = {
  verse: [`Hi matthew`, `Hello God`, `hello guiye`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};

let Mark = {
  verse: [`Hi Mark`, `Hello God`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};
let Luke = {
  verse: [`Hi Luke`, `Hello God`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};
let John = {
  verse: [`Hi John`, `Hello God`],
  book: [`Mark`, `john`]
};

// a new object containing them as properties
let choices = {
  Matthew,
  Mark,
  Luke,
  John
};

document.querySelector('#generate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  userChoice = document.querySelector('#selectValue').value;
  generate(userChoice);
});

function generate(input) {
  // use the string to choose a property from the new object
  let gospel = choices[input];
  
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * gospel.verse.length);
  verseResult = gospel.verse[randomNumber];
  bookResult = gospel.book[randomNumber];
  
  document.querySelector('#verse').innerText = verseResult;
  document.querySelector('#book').innerText = bookResult;
}
```

```html
<form>
    Choose a book : 
    <select id="selectValue">
        <option value="Matthew">Matthew</option>
        <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
        <option value="Luke">Luke</option>
        <option value="John">John</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div class="btn">
    <button id="generate">Generate</button>
</div>
<p>Verse:<span id="verse"></span></p>
<p>Book:<span id="book"></span></p>
```

Comment: DRY - "Don't repeat yourself" ;) - also there are 3 verses in Matthew but only 2 books